# Using an Array instead of an Object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the below object being declared in my application:

```
self.errors = {
    error: {
        status: 404,
        text: 'Missing!'
    }
};
```

Now the above object is aiming to grow with each error triggered by the user, as to provide a list of errors.

Now as far as I am aware, there isn't an easy way for me to add additional `error` properties to this errors object (so I could have one for 405 etc).

But my experience with arrays is very limited. Is there a similar format I could use in an array that I could just push additional `error` sections to the array?

This is assuming there is no easy way to add properties to objects.

Edit: The user's actions will generate this list of errors meaning I can't just use the following structure:

```
self.errors = {
404: "not found",
500: "error text"
};
```

Because the the list will just grow pretty much indefinitely as they keep triggering errors.

Comment: `self.errors = [{status: 404}, {status: 405}, …];`?

Comment: There is an easy way to add properties to objects: just assign them, like `self.errors.newProperty = newValue`. Only one property can be called “error”, though, so your structure doesn’t make a lot of sense.

Comment: prototype error, instantiate errors in each object instance

Comment: You could make the status value be the key instead of just the word "error".

Comment: Create an array by using square braces `[]` and then add your error objects to it. Of course, if your intention is to look up errors by `status`, then it probably makes more sense to have an object which is keyed off the status: `self.errors = { 404 : 'missing', 405: 'whatever' }` for example.

Comment: i think `{404: "missing", 500: "oops" ... }` would be a lot more useful than searching arrays... what matt said...

Comment: @dandavis—until the second 404…

Comment: @RobG: even if that were in an array, how would you know "which" 404 error was which based on the primitives shown by OP? in short, the 2nd 404 doesn't make sense, there's only one afaik. if he had a path or something i'll conced, but with just what's shown, an AoO is inapropos

Comment: @dandavis—arrays have a sequence, and one of the properties can be the time of the error. Many error logs are simple text files with errors added to the bottom. I expect the OP is just an example.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I probably should have mentioned that the errors object im using will be dynamically populated and isnt set to just https status codes. It will contain a multitude of errors ranging from http statuses to form validation warnings.

Comment: @RobG: ok, reread, still unsure. if OP is making a list _for_ user's i'm "right", if OP is making a list _from_ users, you're "right".... that that is unclear, even after a comment from the OP, is regrettable.

Comment: @dandavis You are both right. I am wrong for leaving a real ambiguous use case. I have updated the question, thanks and sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title already suggest the right thing. You are looking for an array of objects

```
self.errors = [{state:404, text: 'Resource not found'}, {state:200, text: 'OK'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess the way to update it is with self.errors.push(objectOfNewError); correct?

Comment: @Aleski: Yeah you're right. But the the solution of Marcos Casagrande is smarter - accessing the elements is 'more natural'.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the following structure, It'll be easy to access each property:

```
self.errors = {
    404: "not found",
    500: "error text"
};
```